# After server migration, Silverstripe 4 throwing error when trying to upload files

Tags: silverstripe, silverstripe-4

I just migrated a SS4 site to a new server. Now, when I try to upload an image, I get the message below. Here is the error I’m seeing:

> ```
> >
> > 
> > Server responded with an error. Authentication required
> > 
> > Unexpected token > in JSON at position
> ```

This is happening even though I have just authenticated as an Admin. I thought it was a permissions problem on the file system, but after looking further into it, that doesn't seem to be the case.

The files do seem to upload, but the preview is not created and does not appear in the preview area. I can save the asset, but not with the "save" and "publish" buttons in the bottom right, I have to use the bulk actions to publish the files. Once I do this, the preview appears.

I'm receiving / have received these error in the console:

```
Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

(async)http://example.com/admin/assets/show/295/edit/307 400 (Bad Request)

GET http://example.com/admin/assets/show/295/edit/307 400 (Bad Request)
```

Anyone have experience with or documentation about this? Not sure how to go about diagnosing/fixing this.

Comment: If you check your network requests tab for the failed form submission request you can take a look at the response, which is probably HTML containing a stack trace. This should tell you what's gone wrong.

Comment: Hi @RobbieAverill, I updated my question with some more info. Would you happen to have more ideas for how to diagnose and fix?